# What is the difference between Places SDK for iOS & Places API under restriction options?

Tags: ios, google-places-api

What is the difference between Places SDK for iOS  & Places API under restriction options?

Answer (score 0):

They're pretty much the same, but some features don't exist in both options.

Here's their respective overviews:

**PLACES SDK** (ref: https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/intro)

> Help your customers explore where they are and what’s around them:
>
> - Current Place returns a list of places where the user’s device is last known to be located along with an indication of the relative
>     likelihood for each place.
> - Place Autocomplete automatically fills in the name and/or address of a place as users type.
> - Place Photos returns high-quality images of a place.
> - Place Details return and display more detailed information about a place.
> - Place IDs stores the unique ID for one or more places for retrieval of place information on demand.
>
> Other highlights of the API include:
>
> - Accurate place detection at low power with WiFi scan.
> - On-device caching: Most requests to the Places SDK for iOS may involve a round trip to a Google server, but you can also cache data
>     locally for 30 days.

**PLACES API** (ref: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/places/)

> - Place Details
>
>   - Provide names, addresses, and other rich details like ratings, reviews, or contact information for over 150 million places.
> - Current Place
>
>   - Identify a place based on real-time signals like time of day or user location.
> - Find Place
>
>   - Turn a phone number, address, or name into a place.
> - Autocomplete
>
>   - Automatically return location suggestions while users type.
> - Geocoding
>
>   - Convert addresses to geographic coordinates, or the reverse.
> - Geolocation
>
>   - Return the precise location of a device based on Wi-Fi or cell towers.
> - Time Zone
>
>   - Return a time zone for any location

To explain, you would want to use the SDK usually for native controls and features such as autocomplete (it uses `UITableView`), place detection at low power, on-device caching.

Meanwhile, you would want to use the places API usually for web-like features such as geocoding, reverse geocoding, directions, distance matrix, and whatnot.